# has_many through rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

**Country Model**

```
set_table_name "countries"

has_many :states, :primary_key => 'col1', :foreign_key => 'col1'

has_many :cities, :through => :states, :primary_key => 'col1', :foreign_key => 'col1'
```

**State Model**

```
set_table_name "strain_appendices"  

belongs_to :country

has_many :states, :primary_key => 'col2', :foreign_key => 'col2'
```

**City Model**

```
set_table_name "ssu_accessions"

belongs_to :country

belongs_to :state
```

**View**

```
<% @countries.each do |country| %>

<%= country.high %>

<% country.states.each do |state| %>

<%= state.high %>

<% country.cities.each do |city| %>

<%= city.high %>
```

`<%= country.high %>` and `<%= state.high %>` give nice output. But, `<%= city.high %>` shows error as "uninitialized constant Country::City". Where may be the problem? Anybody help me?

Comment: It was hiding in some code formatting.

Comment: where are your <%end%> tags ?

Comment: @Bohdan: Sorry, I didnt include <%end%> tags... i apologize...

Answer (score 0):

Unless you define a method named `high` in City model or there's a `high` attribute, you'll get this error.

Maybe you're looking for `city.country.high` or `city.state.high`.

**Edit**

I'm sorry, I misread! As Shadwell said, you'd get another error in the situation described above.

Comment: You'd get method missing wouldn't you? Rather than undefined constant.

Answer (score 0):

In the State model, you are missing this:

```
has_many :cities
```

Comment: Could you please update your question with all the required fields (col1, col2, etc) for each table and also add the end tags on the Loops as well. Thanks.